# Calculando parentesco Javascript false/rue

Tags: javascript, funções, if, return

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver essa questão, deve retorna false/true!

Precisamos criar uma função que verifica se duas pessoas são meio irmãos!

Para que você possa resolver este exercício, definimos para você as funções maeDe e paiDe, que, recebendo um filho (string), retorna o nome (string) da mãe ou pai conforme apropriado. Exemplo:

paiDe(cleoPires)
"Fábio Júnior"
 maeDe(cleoPires)
"Glória Pires"
Agora é a sua vez de criar as funções: temAMesmaMae que tem dois filhos por parâmetro e retornará true oufalse se eles realmente compartilharem a mesma mãe. Sabendo disso você pode usar a função que nós lhe damos maeDe.

temOMesmoPai que como o anterior, pega dois filhos por parâmetro e retorne true oufalse se eles compartilharem o mesmo pai. Sabendo disso você pode usar a função que nós lhe damos paiDe.

E saoMeioIrmaos, que, recebendo dois filhos por parâmetro, nos diga se de fato são meio-irmãos. Você deve usar as duas funções anteriores aqui.

```
function temAMesmaMae(sandy,junior){
  var maeDe(sandy) = "Noely";
  var maeDe(junior) = "Noely";
  return maeDe (sandy) == maeDe ("junior"); 
}

function temOMesmoPai(cleoPires,fiuk){
  var paiDe(cleoPires) = "Fábio Junior";
  var paiDe(fiuk) = "Fábio Junior";
  return paiDe (cleoPires) == paiDe ("fiuk");
}

function saoMeioIrmaos (cleoPires, fiuk){
  var paiDe(cleoPires) = "Fábio Junior";
  var maeDe(cleoPires) = "Glória Pires";
  return maeDe(cleoPires) != maeDe "fiuk";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No Javascript é melhor usar os operadores **===** e **!==** quando for fazer comparação.

A função **temAMesmaMae** recebe 2 strings e compara os valores recebido das função **maeDe** retornando um boolean.

```
function temAMesmaMae(filho1, filho2) {
  return maeDe(filho1) === maeDe(filho2);
}
```

A função **temOMesmoPai** recebe 2 strings e compara os valores recebido da função **paiDe** retornando um boolean.

```
function temOMesmoPai(filho1, filho2) {
  return paiDe(filho1) === paiDe(filho2);
}
```

A função **saoMeioIrmaos** recebe 2 strings, armazena os valores recebido das funções **temAMesmaMae** e **temOMesmoPai** nas variaveis **maes** e **pais** e ela retornará true se as **maes** forem diferentes de **pais** ou vice-versa, em outros casos retornará false.

```
function saoMeioIrmaos(filho1, filho2) {
  const maes = temAMesmaMae(filho1, filho2);
  const pais = temOMesmoPai(filho1, filho2);

  return maes !== pais;
}
```